# Convert Binary File to Words

Tags: binary, hex, ascii

Working in Linux (Ubuntu), I'm trying to assist my elderly father (I'm a senior myself) in recovering data from a file that he insists was originally a text file but it is actually binary and has no file name extension or any readable headers to help determine the application.

Using the following I was able to convert it to ASCII:

> xxd -b 'FILE name'

. . . which gives many lines of code like the following. The first column is hex while all the others are binary. Is there a way to try to convert it to see if it can be something readable?

```
00000000: 11000000 00000100 00000000 00110101 11111100 00010100  ...5..
00000006: 00000110 11000111 11000000 00000100 00000000 00110101  .....5
0000000c: 11111100 00010100 00000110 11000111 11000000 00000100  ......
```

Comment: That's not a text file. It's filled with non-printable characters and NULLs, which means it cannot be text. What ASCII characters it contains are already being displayed; the non-printable chars and NULLs are being represented by periods (dots, or **.**). Your father is mistaken.

Comment: Are you saying that these do not convert to any ASCII characters? He said it was just a list of names and telephone numbers.

Comment: Names and phone numbers would be in printable ASCII characters. Read what I wrote above - the only printable ASCII characters are shown. The ones represented by a dot (a period) are non-printable. I don't know how to say it any more clearly than I did in my first comment. Your father is mistaken if he thinks that is (or was) a text file.

Comment: Yes, but I think he created in some sort of obsolete word processor application as the file was unreadably binary. I converted it to the readable ASCII that I posted.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble understanding. That is **not** readable ASCII that you posted. The only readable characters are the `5`s that are displayed. The other characters are **non-printable characters**, which means they cannot be represented by a character that can be read by eye. Therefore, it is not an ASCII file. Because you didn't get an error running the conversion does not make a binary file magically become readable by eye. For the third time, your father is mistaken. That is **not** a text file. I've repeated it three times now. Go back and read all my comments again.